# enumerated for loop that prints string without whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Trying to produce this as output `1H, 2i, 3p, 4p, 5o, 6p, 7o, 8t, 9a, 10m, 11u, 12s,`

but keep receiving `1 H, 2 i, 3 p, 4 p, 5 o, 6 p, 7 o, 8 t, 9 a, 10 m, 11 u, 12 s,`

```
animal = "Hippopotamus"

for i, letter in enumerate(animal):
    print(i + 1, letter, end = ", ")

1 H, 2 i, 3 p, 4 p, 5 o, 6 p, 7 o, 8 t, 9 a, 10 m, 11 u, 12 s,
```

Comment: Side-note: You can save yourself some math by changing it to `enumerate(animal, start=1)` (`start=` is optional, `enumerate(animal, 1)` also works). Then just `print` `i`, not `i + 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `sep=''` to `print`'s arguments.

Comment: Adding `sep=''` works.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the print function a little like this;

```
animal = "Hippopotamus"

for i, letter in enumerate(animal):
    print(f"{i + 1}{letter}", end = ", " )
```

Or you can use another option like this;

```
for i, letter in enumerate(animal):
    print("{}{}".format(i + 1, letter), end = ", " )
```

Or you can use sep='' in print function.

```
for i, letter in enumerate(animal):
    print(i + 1, letter, end=", ", sep='')
```

Comment: This works, but it's basically bypassing `print` functionality in favor of generating additional temporary strings. `print` does support removing the implicit space separator with `sep=''`.

Comment: Thank you for providing the other options. Adding `sep=''` requires least amount of changes to script.

Answer (score 0):

animal = "Hippopotamus"

for i, letter in enumerate(animal):

```
l = f"{i+1}{letter}"





print(l, end = ", " )
```

Use the f"" string.